# How to hide numbers after dot in float value in input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, numbers

I am developing a financial calculator and i am facing a problem to get exact answers if i round the value . Basically i dont want to show numbers after dot in float value, but i need the same float value in my calculations.
Note :- There are too many calculations so it is tough to save values in variables

for example

```
value1 = Math.round(34.55); // it will be 35
$('#input1').val(value1); // and it is fine to show round value which is 35
value2 = ("#input1").val(); // In this line it will be 35 but i need 34.55
```

Comment: Where 34.55 comes from? Use that direct value.

Comment: you can save 34.55 value in var or hidden html field.When assigning value to value2 use that hidden value

Comment: use jQuery `.data`, to save actual value and use `.val` to display rounded value. for example `$('#input1').data('actual_value',34.55).val(Math.round(34.55));`

Comment: Use a data attribute to store the real value, and the value attribute for the rounded value the user sees

Comment: get the actual value with `$('#input1').data('actual_value');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var floatVal = 34.55;
value1 = Math.round(floatVal); // it will be 35 
$('#input1').attr("data-floatVal","34.55");
$('#input1').val(value1);
//it's important to parseFloat
value2 = parseFloat($("#input1).attr("data-floatVal"));
```

Comment: Use [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) - > `$('#input1').data("actualVal","34.55");` instead of `$('#input1').attr("data-actualVal","34.55");`

Answer (score 0):

set it as an attribute of that input element

```
var decimalValue = 34.55;
$('#input1').attr( "data-value", decimalValue );
$('#input1').val( Math.round( decimalValue ) ); 
value2 = ("#input1).val(); //decimal value
actualValue2 = ("#input1).attr( "data-value" ); // float value
```

Answer (score 0):

try this //I hope this will work for you.
 roundValue = Math.round(34.55); 
 actualValue=34.55;//Create another variable to store actual value and use when required.
$('#input1').val(roundValue);

value2 = actualValue;

```js
try this //I hope this will work for you.
 roundValue = Math.round(34.55); 
 actualValue=34.55;//Create another variable to store actual value and use when required.
$('#input1').val(roundValue);

value2 = actualValue;
```